# My Ubuntu works in USB thumb drive but it's not persistent in spite of 4gb persistence space

Tags: persistence

I installed the LTS distro of Ubuntu on a 32gb flash drive and I can boot to it but there is no persistence. My text files and directory aren't there. Any suggestions?

Comment: I did format a 4gb space for persistence.

Comment: How did you make the Ubuntu drive?
I always use Lili for creating a persistent thumb drive. So far this has always worked fine. This is the link: https://www.linuxliveusb.com/ If you have access to a Windows machine, this can save you a lot of pain.

Comment: 1. Did you make the USB drive bootable in Ubuntu or in Windows or in MacOS? 2. *Which tool* did you use to make the USB drive bootable? 3. Did you add the boot option `persistent` in the syslinux menu or grub menu?